# login form without registration link

Tags: users

How can I get rid of the link for registering a new account in the login form/popup?

I want my new users to register through a page but not through the login form.

Comment: which module are you using for the popup?

Comment: you want to remove registration tab?

Comment: I use Popup, but am considering switching to modal forms. Modal forms has the ability to disable links, but the new-password link is also disabled and i want it to stay.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea for this that you just create your custom module and form_alter function to modify or change the template for login/register/forgot password form. With this way you can handle everything but just in case you want to build your own module. If you want to do this way. I can give you the example code right here.

By the way which drupal version do you use

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [LoginToboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module? This has a number of configurations that are helpful in situations where you would like to customize the login options.

Comment: Didn't try it, but the docs say the customization i need is not in that module. Thanx for pointing me toward that module.